# Constantly getting banned from servers when I try to SSH and/or login

Tags: networking, ssh, fail2ban

We are using `fail2ban`in our servers, and I'm getting banned randomly from them, even if I log in successfully, after typing some chars I get banned.

Also, when I do `scp`, it sometimes starts copying files then I get banned.

I'm the only one in the network that is having this issue.

How can I see if there is some malware in my Ubuntu 16.04 installation? Or maybe some network administrator is sniffing my traffic and causing this?

I'm using encrypted disk, and `terminal` to connect.

Comment: Maybe this problems needs a long dialogue, that you can have at the Ubuntu Forum for networking. See this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=336

Comment: @sudodus I found the problem in the logs, it says: Failed publickey for.... maybe it's because I reinstalled Ubuntu in my PC and changed the key?

Comment: Congratulations :-)